# No color is displayed on the button and no rounding is added to the LinearLayout

Tags: android, xml, android-button

I am developing an android application. I want to add some formatting to my button.

My XML files:

background_button.xml:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="@color/backgroundButton" />
        <corners android:radius="0dip" />
    </shape>
</item>
</selector>
```

Button XML code:

```
<Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/go_to_course"
            android:textAlignment="textStart"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/right_arrow"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:background="@drawable/background_button" />
```

1. For some reason, a purple color is applied, and not the one I indicated (light gray). All paths are correct.

colors.xml

```
<resources>
    <color name="black">#FF000000</color>
    <color name="white">#FFFFFFFF</color>
    <color name="mainBackground">#F5F6F8</color>
    <color name="backgroundButton">#FFF1F2F4</color>
</resources>
```

right_arrow.xml

```
<vector android:height="25dp" android:viewportHeight="800"
    android:viewportWidth="1653" android:width="51.65625dp" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <path android:fillColor="#00000000"
        android:pathData="M29,400H1446.4M1446.4,400L1239.8,500M1446.4,400L1239.8,300"
        android:strokeColor="#000000" android:strokeLineCap="round"
        android:strokeLineJoin="round" android:strokeWidth="50"/>
</vector>
```

2. At the same time I want to know why they don’t want to apply rounding on the LinearLayout:

```
<LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:background="@drawable/corners_10">
    
                <Button
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/go_to_course"
                    android:textAlignment="textStart"
                    android:drawableRight="@drawable/right_arrow"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:background="@drawable/background_button" />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView2"
                    android:background="@color/backgroundButton"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:text="@string/text" />
           </LinearLayout>
```

And the XML file is the same as on the button, just the corners are indicated by 10 dip.

Please help me with two questions. Thank you!

Comment: Please add your `colors.xml` file to the question

Comment: Added. Maybe it's the theme of the application or not?

Comment: For your first question, I think that using `android:drawableRight="@drawable/right_arrow"` changes the button colour. Could you also add the `right_arrow.xml`

Comment: @Dinux added changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your 1st question, you want to change the background colour of your button. To do that, you have to replace `Button` with `androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton`. Modified code:

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/go_to_course"
            android:textAlignment="textStart"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/right_arrow"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:background="@drawable/background_button" />
```

As for your 2nd question, if you want the rounded corners of the  `LinearLayout` to be visible, you can add `android:paddingBottom`. Modified code:

```
<LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:background="@drawable/corners_10"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:paddingTop="10dp">
    
                <Button
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/go_to_course"
                    android:textAlignment="textStart"
                    android:drawableRight="@drawable/right_arrow"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:background="@drawable/background_button" />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView2"
                    android:background="@color/backgroundButton"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:text="@string/text" />
           </LinearLayout>
```

You can adjust the `android:paddingBottom` and `android:paddingTop` to your liking. Then you will be able to add square elements without the rounded corners getting hidden.

Comment: If I apply the styles you said, then I won't be able to make custom rounding for the button. And on the 2nd question, I would like to know how to make it so that I can put square elements inside layout, and layout cut them off at the edges, that is, add rounding to the parent. Maybe it's done in some other way, I just need to implement exactly this appearance, and in what ways, it doesn't matter anymore.